# SQL Server 2005 Reporting Services (x64) on Windows 2K8 -> CleanCurrentUserName() not found

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services, 64-bit, windows-server-2008

I have installed SQL Server 2005 three times now on the same box.  I cleaned up registry settings, files, you name it.

All along I have been trying to install SQL Server 2005 Database and Reporting Services (x64) on a Windows 2008 Server.  I have also applied the SP3 patch.  Installing and Restarting the Server at every point.  Verified that the installation was 64bit.  ASP.NET and IIS7 are both running under 64bit.

Also, I have installed multiple instances (SQLDEV64, SQLQA64, SQLSTAGE64) of the Database and Reporting Services.

I started to go through the Reporting Services Configuration manager, installing the Reporting Database along with setting up IIS.  When I go test the website I get the following error and there lies my question.  How can I get around this error?

http://localhost/reportserver

```
Reporting Services Error
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

An internal error occurred on the report server. See the error log for more details. (rsInternalError) 
Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.UserUtil.CleanCurrentUserName()'. 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL Server Reporting Services
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my issue by pure chance.  It looks like the SP3 upgrade only upgraded the last reporting services instance that was installed.  So I had to manually copy the files under:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.9\Reporting Services\ReportServer
```

to the other instances.  This seemed to fix the missing reference issue.  I work with Microsoft products and defend them every day, but some of their developer tool install files are just wonky and ill packaged.